# What is Representable used for in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functor, category-theory

I am looking to understand what does [Representable](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/adjunctions-4.4/docs/Data-Functor-Rep.html#t:Representable) stand for in Haskell. The definition

> Representable endofunctors over the category of Haskell types are isomorphic to the reader monad and so inherit a very large number of properties for free.

is not clear enough to me. I would like to take a look at a real example, to understand how can I use `tabulate` and `index` methods.

**So, my question is:**

- What is Representable used for?
- Can you clarify the definition and provide an example, please?

Comment: This could use more detail about what you do and don't understand. For instance are you comfortable with type families? With type classes generally?

Comment: @jberryman Yes, I am pretty familiar with type classes. To be honest, I don't have a clear idea what is a monad, but functor is quite clear to me.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`Representable`s are containter-like functors that have a "special relationship" with another type that serves as an index into the `Representable`. In the Haskell definition, this index type is given by the associated type family `type Rep f :: *`

For *every* value of the index and for *every* value of the `Representable`, we can call the `index :: f a -> Rep f -> a` function to get the corresponding element. And `tabulate :: (Rep f -> a) -> f a` constructs a container where each element is derived from its own index.

Now, here is an example of a functor that is NOT representable: the typical Haskell list type `[]`. One might naively think that it can be indexed by something like a [`Natural`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/GHC-Natural.html), but the problem is that lists can be empty, or not have enough elements to reach a given index.

An always-infinite type like `data Stream a = Stream a (Stream a)` *is* `Representable` and it's indexed by `Natural`, because there will always be a value for any given `Natural` that we pass to `index`.

Similarly, the homogeneous pair `data Pair a = Pair a a` is indexed by the type `Bool`: the index tells us which of the components to select.

If we get dependent-ish, [fixed-size vectors](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vec-0.1/docs/Data-Vec-Pull.html#t:Vec) are `Representable` and are indexed by [finite naturals](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fin-0.0.1/docs/Data-Fin.html#t:Fin) bounded by the size of the vector. They aren't indexed by unbounded `Natural`s  because then we could have an out-of-bounds access!

---

Reading the various instances defined for `Representable` is instructive, but it seems we have to get down to the source code because the associated types are not visible in the Haddocks. Some interesting tidbits:

- The `Identity` functor is indexed by the unit type `()`, this makes sense because `Identity` only has one "slot" so to speak, so we don't need to provide any information.
- The "functions from some type" type `((->) e)` is indexed by the source type itself. And `index` is simply `id`. This is what's meant by "isomorphic to the reader monad", because the `Reader e` monad is just a newtype over `((->) e)`.
- The [`Composition`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-Functor-Compose.html#t:Compose) (nesting) of two representable functors is again `Representable`, and it is indexed by the *pair* of the original indexes! This makes sense: first we must know how to index into the outer functor, and then into the inner one.
- The [`Product`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-Functor-Product.html#t:Product) (pairing) of two `Representable` functors is indexed by the sum (`Either`) of the original indexes. The branch of the `Either` tells us in which part of the product to index.
- A notable omission (because it is not true in general): there is no `(Representable f, Representable g) => Representable (Sum f g)` instance.

Comment: An example of a package which provides Representable instances for its core data type: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/grids And also https://twitter.com/phadej/status/1037667021968822272

Comment: I would add that, in general, product types are representable, whereas sum types are not. The intuition is that the representation is like a logarithm of a data structure (that's because the function type is an exponential). A logarithm of a product is a sum of logarithms. But, in general, there is no simple formula for a logarithm of a sum. The list is not representable because it's a sum of Nil and Cons. A stream is representable because it has no Nil, and Cons is a product.

Comment: Vectors as functors represented by Fin in Idris: https://blog.cofree.coffee/2020-10-17-bounded-space-automata/ https://blog.cofree.coffee/2020-12-22-finally-modular-arithmetic/

Comment: Does this actually have anything to do with how representable functors are used in category theory? (i.e., you want to show that a classifying space exists, but cannot be bothered explicitly constructing it, so instead you construct the functor represented by it, and then appeal to some general criterion, e.g., the [Brown representability theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown%27s_representability_theorem), to prove that this functor is indeed represented by a space.)