# Implementing Applicative instance for dictionaries (Map, associated arrays)

Tags: haskell, data-structures, functional-programming, separation-of-concerns

It seems straightforward to implement a functor instance (essentially a mapping operation) for associated arrays (e.g. see `Functor` definition [1]). However, `Applicative` instance is not defined. Is there a good theoretical reason that Maps are not Applicatives? What additional constrains are required for them to be Applicatives?

[1] https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.3.1/docs/Data-Map-Strict.html

Comment: I can't give a theoretical argument, but it seems clear that you certainly can't even eg. write a general `pure :: v -> Map k v` that works for any `k`. (It would presumably be a singleton map but what key would you put the value at?) Nor is it clear how, if you solved that problem (which you can, by picking a specific type or set of types for `k`), you would implement `<*>`. At least it isn't to me - whereas with `fmap` there's basically a very obvious thing you can do, that works.

Comment: @RobinZigmond there is an “obvious” way how `<*>` should behave: intersection of the key sets. But that only forms a valid `Applicative` if `pure` generates a _constant map_, i.e. one that contains _every possible key_. Not really practical!

Comment: @leftaroundabout fair point, I did think of that after writing my comment but didn't fully think it through.

Comment: It seems practical, as in there's a simple finite representation, but it's not useful perhaps? @leftroundabout

Comment: Actually it would be just like the Applicative instance for `ZipList`, if one thinks of lists as like `Maps` whose keys are non-negative integers. It does certainly seem theoretically possible, but unlike infinite lists I assume general infinite maps simply wouldn't work in practice.

Comment: On a relevant note, the semigroupoids packages gives an `Ord k => Apply (Map k)` instance, with a note about lacking `pure` for applicative. Whilst you can easily write a Map structure that would provide necessary support for a default / "at every non-present key" value required for `pure`, the data structure provided in base does not have it.

Comment: I'd point out that "potentially infinite `Map k`" is basically just one step removed from `(->) k`(/`MaybeT ((->) k)`?), whose `Applicative` does have "zippy" behavior.

Comment: @HTNW, yeah, you could totally do that. The problem is that unless you have something rather stronger than just `Ord k`, the implementation seems guaranteed to potentially leak space.

Comment: @moonGoose I meant _not practical_ WRT to `Data.Map` itself, which really does store every key/value pair separately so for most types `pure x` would consume all memory to fully build up. I wonder if laziness could come to the rescue. But as (I think?) you say, a more practical way would be to add a `Global x | Partial (Map k x)` wrapper, to get that behaviour.

Comment: @leftroundabout I think the representation is `MapNormal (Map k v) | MapConstant v (Map k v) `. Then `Map.singleton 0 0 == MapNormal (Map.fromList [(0,0)])`, `pure 0 & at 0 ?~ 1 == MapConstant 0 (Map.fromList [(0,1)])`, ie. you can represent a (empty or constant) map with a finite number of modifications applied, whereas your representation can't do the second example. No space leakage as far as I can see, with natural implementation for `<*>`.

Comment: @HTNW That kind of map isomorphic to `(->) k` is a `Representable`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54261967/what-is-representable-used-for-in-haskell

Comment: @moonGoose, your `MapNormal` can't be *edited* the way a `Map` can.

Comment: @dfeuer can you expand on that thought? I see how you can't do eg. stuff with minimal / maximal elements without `Bounded k`, lose the `lookupXX` and various traversal/folding functions. I think you can still get reasonable functionality of lookup, modification, union/intersection?

Comment: @moonGoose, the fundamental problem is that you never know when you're done with the "default" element. That's okay if the domain is infinite, but otherwise not.

Comment: @dfeuer I trust your expertise, but I don't know how you arrived at that conclusion - could you explain or point to appropriate resources? Also, it's isomorphic to a `Map (Maybe k) v` where the default value is optionally present at `Nothing`, would that work instead? Ie. is the issue in the data declaration as given or arises necessarily when modifying the structure?

Comment: @moonGoose, suppose you start with `pure enormousThing :: Mappish Int8 Whatever`. Then use `insert` to edit the `Mappish` for every single `Int8`. Now the `enormousThing` will never be used again, but the `Mappish` doesn't know that and must keep holding on to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As folks have pointed out in the comments, you can’t implement a valid `Applicative` instance for `Map` because you can’t implement `pure` in a law-abiding way. Because of the identity law, `pure id <*> v` = `v`, the `pure` implementation needs to maintain all of the keys while intersecting the maps with function application. You can’t do that for partial maps because, by parametricity, you may not have a key in one map or the other from which to conjure the function `a -> b` or argument `a` that you need to produce a `b` in the resulting map. `pure x` would need to work like the one for `ZipList` (which uses `repeat`), producing a map that maps *every* key to the same value `x`, but this isn’t possible with `Map` because it’s finite. However, it *is* possible with alternative representations that allow infinite maps, such as a map based on functions and `Eq`.

```
-- Represent a map by its lookup function.
newtype EqMap k v = EM (k -> Maybe v)

-- Empty: map every key to ‘Nothing’.
emEmpty :: EqMap k v
emEmpty = EM (const Nothing)

-- Singleton: map the given key to ‘Just’ the given value,
-- and all other keys to ‘Nothing’.
emSingleton :: (Eq k) => k -> v -> EqMap k v
emSingleton k v = EM (\ k' -> if k == k' then Just v else Nothing)

-- Insertion: add an entry that overrides any earlier entry
-- for the same key to return ‘Just’ a new value.
emInsert :: (Eq k) => k -> v -> EqMap k v -> EqMap k v
emInsert k v (EM e) = EM (\ k' -> if k == k' then Just v else e k')

-- Deletion: add an entry that overrides any earlier entry
-- for the same key to return ‘Nothing’.
emDelete :: (Eq k) => k -> EqMap k v -> EqMap k v
emDelete k (EM e) = EM (\ k' -> if k == k' then Nothing else e k')

emLookup :: EqMap k v -> k -> Maybe v
emLookup (EM e) = e

instance Functor (EqMap k) where

  -- Map over the return value of the lookup function.
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> EqMap k a -> EqMap k v
  fmap f (EM e) = EM (fmap (fmap f) e)

instance Applicative (EqMap k) where

  -- Map all keys to a constant value.
  pure :: a -> EqMap k a
  pure x = EM (const (Just x))

  -- Intersect two maps with application.
  (<*>) :: EqMap k (a -> b) -> EqMap k a -> EqMap k b
  fs <*> xs = EM (\ k -> emLookup k fs <*> emLookup k xs)
```

Unfortunately, this isn’t just infinite semantically: as you add *or remove* key–value pairs, it also *grows* infinitely in memory! This is because the entries are a linked list of closures, not reified as a data structure: you can only remove values from the map by *adding* an entry indicating their removal, like a reversion in a version control system. It’s also very inefficient for lookups, which are linear in the number of keys, rather than logarithmic for `Map`. At best it’s an okay academic exercise for a beginner-intermediate functional programmer, just to get a feel for how to represent things with functions.

A simple alternative here is a “default map” that maps nonexistent keys to a constant value.

```
data DefaultMap k v = DM v (Map k v)

dmLookup :: (Ord k) => k -> DefaultMap k v -> v
dmLookup k (DM d m) = fromMaybe d (Map.lookup k m)

-- …
```

Then the implementation of `Applicative` is straightforward: the intersection of the existing keys, plus the nonexistent keys applied with the default.

```
instance Functor (DefaultMap k) where

  -- Map over the return value of the lookup function.
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> DefaultMap k a -> DefaultMap k b
  fmap f (DM d m) = DM (f d) (fmap f m)

instance Applicative (DefaultMap k) where

  -- Map all keys to a constant value.
  pure x = DM x mempty

  -- Intersect two maps with application, accounting for defaults.
  DM df fs <*> DM dx xs = DM (df dx) $ Map.unions
    [ Map.intersectionWith ($) fs xs
    , fmap ($ dx) fs
    , fmap (df $) xs
    ]
```

`DefaultMap` is slightly unusual in that you *can* delete key–value pairs, but only by effectively “resetting” them to their default value, in that a lookup for a given key will always succeed even after a deletion of that same key. Although you can of course recover something resembling the partial behaviour of `Map` using `DefaultMap k (Maybe v)` with a default of `Nothing` and an invariant of always mapping defined keys to `Just`.

I *think* there’s also an `instance Monad (DefaultMap k)`, by isomorphism with `instance Monad ((->) k)` or `instance Monad (Stream k)`, since like `Stream`, a `DefaultMap` is *always* infinite—whereas the possibly-finite `ZipList` can’t have a `Monad` instance because it necessarily violates the associativity law `a >=> (b >=> c)` = `(a >=> b) >=> c`.