# Instance Applicative of a datatype

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write an instance of Applicative for my datatype

```
data Multinode k v = Multinode { key :: k
                               , values :: [v]
                               } deriving Show

data Multimap k v = Multimap [Multinode k v] deriving Show
```

I'm still learning Haskell. So I may make funny mistakes. If I understood properly, Applicative is a subset of Functor. The operators that have to be defined are `pure` and `<*>`.

`pure :: a -> f a`

`(<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`

My attempt is the following

```
instance Applicative (Multimap k) where
  pure x = Multimap [(Multinode x [x])]
  (Multimap mf@((Multinode kf vsf):nsf)) <*> (Multimap mx@((Multinode kx vsx):nsx)) =
Multimap [Multinode kf (vsf <*> vsx)]
```

Comment: So, what happens when you try that?

Comment: As far as `Applicative` is concerned, only type constructors with 1 free type parameter can be made an instance of it; indeed you'r making `Multimap k`, not `Multimap` an instance of it. However, your implementation of `pure` forces `v` to be `[k]` for `Multinode`, and for `Multimap` as a consequence. I think this is not intended. Maybe you just have to think a bit more about it. And maybe clarify the question.

Comment: You should edit to make your question explicit. Do you get an error or unexpected result? Generally, a map type can be `Applicative` only if it can have a “default” value, e.g. `data M k v = M v [N k v]`. If you want `f <*> x` to apply each function in `f` to each value in `x` at the same key, then because the identity law requires `pure id <*> m` = `m`, `pure id` must map *every key* to `id`. This is like `ZipList`, where `pure x = ZipList (repeat x)`, acting like a map with natural-number keys (list indices). See [my answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63460162/246886).

Comment: @JonPurdy a map type that *can* have a “default” value would be `data M k v = M (Maybe v) [N k v]`, isn't it.

Comment: @WillNess: Right! Mine can and cannot not, while yours can or can not, but not *cannot*, obviously. Glad I could clear that up, but didn’t.

Comment: @JonPurdy I just thought it was important to mention, for some reason. if that was out of line, I apologize. it's just that to have an *intersection* we must intersect with a map without a default, was my thinking...

Comment: @WillNess: Oh not at all, I’m just being silly, sorry if I came off as snippy. You raise a good point: a map that *can’t* be empty is a bit weird! There are some tradeoffs. As I mention in my linked answer, you can recover empty maps by passing in a `Maybe`-wrapped type for the `v` parameter (`M @K @(Maybe V)`), which amounts to the difference between “nontotal lookups” (`Kleisli Maybe K V`) and “total lookups of optional values” (`Kleisli Identity K (Maybe V)`), tomato tomato.

Answer (score 5):

Maps and multimaps are not naturally `Applicative`. Here's why: you need

```
pure
  :: (...) -- Possible constraint involving k, but not v
  =>  v -> MultiMap k v
```

Since there are no constraints on `v`, `pure` cannot use its argument to generate any keys. So the set of keys in the result must always be the same, which doesn't work out for any meaningful notion of `<*>` that I know of.

The `semigroupoids` package offers a class called [`Apply`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroupoids-5.3.5/docs/Data-Functor-Apply.html#t:Apply), which is much more promising:

```hs
class Functor f => Apply f where
  (<.>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
  liftF2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c
  (.>) :: f a -> f b -> f b
  (<.) :: f a -> f b -> f a
```

This is just like `Applicative` but without `pure`. `<.>` is analogous to `<*>`, `liftF2` is analogous to `liftA2`, etc. The `semigroupoids` package includes an instance `Ord k => Apply (Map k)`. You should be able to think of a couple different instances for your type based on the general idea of that one.

Comment: Another alternative is to include a default value that's returned when a key doesn't exist; then you could have a `pure` that sets the default and has no keys.

Comment: @DanielWagner, that would be a somewhat different structure, a map-with-default.

Comment: Sure, meanwhile your answer talks about a somewhat different interface, an Applicative-without-pure. Sometimes one shift is appropriate, sometimes the other.