# Haskell : what is the sense in: instance Functor ((->) r)

Tags: haskell, functor

I admit, that my question may stem from a lack of knowledge and be rather vague.
But I try to understand, have some doubts and can't resolve them.

So GHC.Base have such definition, and what is the sense in it:

```
instance Functor ((->) r) where
    fmap = (.)
```

1. From the viewpoint of programming language:
   We have really base construction (->), I think more base than anything, but maybe terms, and you describe it as a part of very derivative construction (instance Functor). What is the sense? (->) is (->). Functor have any sense as far as (->) described under Haskell hood meaningfully. But not vice versa: (->) have sense while Functor described in Haskell libraries correctly.
2. From the viewpoint of lambda calculus:
   2.1 If from "common sense" definition "(->) r" is a container around r (let's call it "Any_f"), then how function fmap shoul work?
   fmap should change value into container, but do not change container-structure, try to write it.

   fmap f (Any_f x) <=> Any_f (f x)

(yes, this is non-typed lambda calculus)

2.2. But let's look how Functor ((->) r) defined in Haskell:

```
instance Functor ((->) r) where
    fmap = (.)
    -- Or in other words (quotation marks intentionaly):
    -- fmap f (Any_f x) = f (Any_f x) 
    -- fmap :: forall a, b, c => (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)
```

So:

- "common sense" (not change container structure) tells us to write:

  fmap f (Any_f_as_container x) = Any_f_as_container (f x)
- types requirements tell us to write:

  fmap f (any_f_as_container x) = f (Any_f_as_container x)

Doesn't this means that "instance Functor ((->) r)" is meaningless? And if not - what sense does it has when it changes outermost function (container itself, not container value)?

Comment: I have a hard time following your reasoning. Note that you can think `(->) r` as a types-to-types function that maps any type `t` to the function type `r -> t`. If `r=Bool`, for example, then `r->t` is `Bool->t` which is isomorphic to `(t,t)` -- a container with two values of type `t` inside. Generalizing, `r->t` is a "container" containing as many values of type `t` as the number of possible values of type `r` (possibly infinitely many).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will try to convince you that `fmap = (.)` really is a thing that leaves a container's shape the same, but applies a function to all the elements in the container. But before we do that for `(->)`, let's do it for some simpler types. Specifically, let's do it for types that are containers with a specific number of elements -- i.e., a container with exactly two elements will be `TwoF`, while one with no elements will be `ZeroF`. Like this:

```
data ZeroF  a = ZeroF
data OneF   a = OneF   a
data TwoF   a = TwoF   a a
data ThreeF a = ThreeF a a a
```

What should the `Functor` instances for these look like? Well, the one for `OneF` looks *exactly* like in your question:

```
instance Functor OneF where
    fmap f (OneF x) = OneF (f x)
```

The other ones look *pretty* similar -- just applying `f` more (or fewer) times to account for the fact that there are more (or fewer) elements. Here they all are, with some creative whitespace to highlight the similarities/pattern:

```
instance Functor ZeroF  where fmap f (ZeroF          ) = ZeroF
instance Functor OneF   where fmap f (OneF   x0      ) = OneF   (f x0)
instance Functor TwoF   where fmap f (TwoF   x0 x1   ) = TwoF   (f x0) (f x1)
instance Functor ThreeF where fmap f (ThreeF x0 x1 x2) = ThreeF (f x0) (f x1) (f x2)
```

Hopefully for now you agree that this definitely has the flavor of `Functor` instance that you described in your question: keep the shape of the container the same, and apply the given function `f` to each element contained within.

So those are containers with a given number of elements. Now, let's write accessors for these containers -- i.e. we want the equivalent of `(!!)` for lists, where given a number, we pull out that field from the container. Since there's zero elements in a `ZeroF`, we'll need an indexing type with zero values; while for `ThreeF` we need an indexing type with three values.

```
data Zero
data One   = One0
data Two   = Two0   | Two1
data Three = Three0 | Three1 | Three2
```

The indexing functions have types that look like this:

```
indexZero  :: ZeroF  a -> Zero  -> a
indexOne   :: OneF   a -> One   -> a
indexTwo   :: TwoF   a -> Two   -> a
indexThree :: ThreeF a -> Three -> a
```

I won't implement them all -- they're pretty straightforward -- but here's one to give you the idea in case it's not immediately obvious.

```
indexTwo (TwoF x0 x1) Two0 = x0
indexTwo (TwoF x0 x1) Two1 = x1
```

It turns out that the indexing functions have an inverse -- if you give me a function which, when given an index, produces a value, then I can give you a container with those values in it. The types look like this:

```
tabulateZero  :: (Zero  -> a) -> ZeroF  a
tabulateOne   :: (One   -> a) -> OneF   a
tabulateTwo   :: (Two   -> a) -> TwoF   a
tabulateThree :: (Three -> a) -> ThreeF a
```

(Do you see why this is the right type for an inverse? Note that, say, `TwoF a -> Two -> a` is the same type as `TwoF a -> (Two -> a)`!) Just to give you an idea of how these are implemented, in case it's not immediately obvious, we simply apply the indexing function to each index:

```
tabulateZero  ix = ZeroF
tabulateOne   ix = OneF   (ix One0  )
tabulateTwo   ix = TwoF   (ix Two0  ) (ix Two1  )
tabulateThree ix = ThreeF (ix Three0) (ix Three1) (ix Three2)
```

It's not too hard to prove that `tabulateX . indexX = id` and `indexX . tabulateX = id` for each `X`, i.e. that tabulation really is the inverse of indexing.

Okay, but hold up now and take a look at what we've just done: we have turned a *function* (like `Two -> a`) into a *container* (like `TwoF a`), and vice versa. The types `Two -> a` and `TwoF a` are, morally speaking, *exactly the same thing*. So it seems reasonable to think we could implement `fmap` for `Two -> a` -- for example, just by converting to `TwoF a` and back as appropriate!

```
twomap :: (a -> b) -> (Two -> a) -> (Two -> b)
twomap f = indexTwo . fmap f . tabulateTwo
```

Let's visualize what that's doing. We'll start with an arbitrary indexing function:

```
\case Two0 -> x0; Two1 -> x1
```

Now we go through the process:

```
               \case Two0 -> x0; Two1 -> x1
tabulateTwo
               TwoF x0 x1
fmap f
               TwoF (f x0) (f x1)
indexTwo
               \case Two0 -> f x0; Two1 -> f x1
```

Since `f` gets applied in both branches, we could pull that out of the `case`:

```
               f . (\case Two0 -> x0; Two1 -> x1)
```

That second term is exactly the indexing function we started out with. In other words, we have just determined another, simpler implementation for `twomap`:

```
twomap f ix = f . ix
```

If you work through similar reasoning for `zeromap`, `onemap`, and `threemap`, you'll discover they actually all have that same implementation! We can do this uniformly for all the various sizes of container just by going polymorphic; instead of having `onemap` for changing `One -> a`'s, etc., let's have an `xmap` for changing `x -> a`'s:

```
xmap :: (a -> b) -> (x -> a) -> (x -> b)
xmap f ix = f . ix
```

Of course, we don't have to name `f` and `ix`:

```
xmap = (.)
```

...and this is the `Functor` instance for `(x -> _)`.

Comment: Thank you.
Now I'm thinking of such a thing: 
((->) a b) <=> Set a b -- these are literally equivalent things for functions with finite possible argument.

but why applying (fmap f) looks so different:
 - fmap f someSet: we have to invade into Set a b, and apply f only to "b" values
 - fmap f (someFunc x): we just call f (someFunc x).

Comment: @KonstantinKazartsev I don't know what `Set a b` means. The `Set` I know takes just one type argument. But I will note that in `f (someFunc x)` we are exactly applying `f` only to `b` values.

Comment: Of course Map a b, not Set (my bad -- it's already deep past midnight).

Comment: @KonstantinKazartsev `a -> b` is *similar* to `Map a b` -- but they are not quite alike. A `Map` need not have a value for every possible key, but a function must.

Comment: @KonstantinKazartsev Daniel Wagner's idea of "map-like things that must have a value for every possible key" is captured by the `Representable` typeclass, which is a subclass of `Functor`. https://hackage.haskell.org/package/adjunctions-4.4/docs/Data-Functor-Rep.html#t:Representable https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54261967/what-is-representable-used-for-in-haskell

Comment: @danidiaz I'v thought that (lookup x map == Nothing) <=> (f x == undefined).
Is this a dirty trick?

Comment: @KonstantinKazartsev And what of `lookup x map == Just undefined`?

Comment: Thank you it's reasonable: better to use Just^-1 => f x <=>(is equals) fromJust $ lookup x map

Answer (score 1):

`(->)` isn't just syntax. It's an operator like any other, but at the *type* level instead of the term level. It has a *kind* `Type -> Type -> Type`, which means if you apply it to a single type, you get back not a type, but another "function" of kind `Type -> Type`.

`Type -> Type` is the kind of *all* functors, so it's reasonable to think the partially applied `(->)` operator might be a functor as well, which is what

```
instance Functor ((->) r) where
    fmap = (.)
```

defines. That is, mapping a function over another function means to compose the two functions.

As a "container", think of a function (something of type `r -> a`) as containing all possible values of type `a` that you can get by applying the function to an argument of type `r`. `fmap` will apply a function to whatever the other function returns. (Or in theory, apply it to *every* value that the other could return.)

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is: functions can be represent either as `(a -> b)` or as `Map a b` - for function with finite count of possible arguments these are literally two equivalent representations.

So `instance Functor (Map r)` is meaningful and it would be implemented just as `instance Functor ((->) r)` implemented already.

And the answer above is confirmed by the implementation of `instance Functor ((,) r)`. Yes this is a bit different than `Map r`, but as close as possible.

P.S.
@chepner : I can't mark your answer as "best answer" because I don't understand (and almost don't agree) with one word in one sentense:

> (->) isn't just syntax. It's an operator **like any other**

Function is not "like any other" operation (I used notion "construction") function is magical- or under-hood-compiler- construction, on which all other fuctions are based.

Comment: Don't call it `Set a b`. However, `Trie a b` would fit the bill, or [`:->:` from the `MemoTrie` package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MemoTrie-0.6.10/docs/Data-MemoTrie.html#t::-45--62-:).

Comment: Of course Map, not Set - thank you.
But if "Trie, but not Map" - explain please why (assuming "lookup x m == Nothing <=> f x == undefined")?

Comment: Compare `(->)` to `(+)`. What do you find different between them? I would argue most of the differences stem from the distinction between types and terms, not anything specific to `(->)` itself.

Comment: (In a looser sense, `(->)` is overloaded to operate on the *kind* level as well, as `Type` and `Type -> Type` are both kinds. Basically, `(->)` just doesn't work on *terms*.)

Comment: @chepner - unfortunately I haven't understood you (in due a lack of knowledge). But I'll try later. Thank you.