# Fmapping over functors

Tags: haskell

Say I have the following code:

```
data LiftItOut f a = LiftItOut (f a)
    deriving Show

instance (Functor fct) => Functor (LiftItOut fct) where
    fmap f (LiftItOut fctor) = LiftItOut (fmap f fctor)
```

If I try calling `fmap (\x-> 3 x) (LiftItOut (+3))` it doesn't work. Though, wouldn't it make sense to work? The result would be `LiftItOut (fmap (\x ->3 x) (+3))` and, as I see it, the 3 would be fed to (+3) and the result would be wrapped in **LiftItOut**. I read about *(->r)* functors on learnyouahaskell though it didn't click with me. Appreciate any and every bit of help

Comment: What do you think the final result would be, and what type do you think it would have?

Comment: `\x -> 3 x` makes no sense (although unfortunately the error message you will get from GHC is needlessly confusing, because it's *theoretically* possible this would make sense, it just can't in sensible practice). Did you mean `\x -> x 3` (which can also be written as `($ 3)`?

Comment: @RobinZigmond Yes, I was aiming for function application of 3 to the (+3)

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I guess the resulting type would be a LiftItOut (f a), so a functor of LiftItOut type? So my pick of a function to apply is wrong, and even if I calculate it I wouldn't be able to show it cause it's a functor?

Comment: Start with setting `LiftItOut` aside. What the result of `fmap (\x-> 3 x) (+3)` (or `fmap ($3) (+3)` or whatever) should be?

Comment: What function do you think solves `f . (+3) == (f + 3)`? That's what you are looking for, since `fmap` for functions is *composition*, not application.

Comment: I am skeptical that `LiftItOut` is a useful thing to define (at least until you get significantly more experienced with Haskell and get to the point where performance tuning matters). Why bother with a thing of type `LiftItOut f a` when you could just have a thing of type `f a` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right in that you'd get to `LiftItOut (fmap (\x -> 3 x) (+3))`, and you correctly identified that the wrapped functor of interest is the function functor (N.B. the `(r ->)` functor, not the `(-> r)` functor), but your reasoning from there got a bit sloppy. Recall that [for functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75051452/791604), we have `fmap = (.)`. So:

```
LiftItOut (fmap (\x -> 3 x) (+3))
= { fmap = (.) }
LiftItOut ((\x -> 3 x) . (+3))
= { f . g = \y -> f (g y) }
LiftItOut (\y -> (\x -> 3 x) ((+3) y))
= { section application }
LiftItOut (\y -> (\x -> 3 x) (y + 3))
= { lambda application }
LiftItOut (\y -> 3 (y + 3))
```

...not *exactly* the result you were thinking you'd get, I wager! And hopefully in this simplified form it's more clear why this isn't really sensible: `y + 3` is probably sensible enough, but you are attempting to provide that as an argument to `3`, which isn't really a function.

Comment: Thanks, cleared it up for me (mostly). Though, am I looking to have a function wrapped in LiftItOut as a result, judging by how fmap is defined in the instance? As in, if the function in the last line of your code section were to be properly defined, would it be the correct type?

Comment: @DuduDudu I... don't really know. I guess it's somewhat tautological to say "if it were correct, then it would be correct". What does "properly defined" mean to you?

Comment: The resulting value from the expression `LiftItOut (fmap f fctor)` should be a functor, according to my logic. So a LiftItOut (--insert function here--) would technically be a functor right? The more I think I understand functors, the further away from light I am, lol

Comment: Your problem is that you are trying to use *3* as a function. There is no `Num` instance that allows you to do that.

Comment: @DuduDudu Yes, `LiftItOut f` is an object which you can call `fmap` on whenever `f` is a function. (Note, that was worded fairly carefully. Although most people  will probably understand what you mean, it would be sloppy to say "`LiftItOut f` is a functor", because a functor is a pair (X, x) of a type X and a function x with certain properties.)